# how to perform this count line operation with division in bash

Tags: bash, shell

my goal is to split a file into chunks. Lets say I have a file with 100 lines.
I want to use a bash script to divide it into 4 chunks. The way I am doing it is to count how many line are there in the document. Then, I specify the number of document I want to split into. I do the calculation to get the chucks' line number, then use the split command with -l option.

I tried this:

```
    echo "Please specify the number of chunks you want to split"
    read chunks
    echo "Preparing the input files......................"
    echo "Please Enter your input file directory"
    read inputDir
    echo "Spliting the input file into chunks"
    split -l=$(($((wc -l $inputDir))/$(($chunks-1)))) $inputDir
```

and it gives me this error: (Say I enter 5 here and want to get 4 files with 25 lines each)

```
    syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/3")
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to split the input directory here, not the actual files in it. Get all the files in the directory then split them.

Comment: yes, I just want to split the file in the bash script. I want to do it in one hash line. How do I edit my last line to make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wc` outputs the name of the file it counts. To prevent that, use redirection:

```
$(( $(wc -l < $inputDir) / (chunks - 1) ))
```

`$inputFile` is a better variable name, unless you really want to process a directory. You can't count lines in a directory with `wc`, though.

Also note that you don't need to nest arithmetic expansions `$((...))`.

Moreover, your `split` might support the `-n` option:

> -n, --number=CHUNKS
>
> generate CHUNKS output files.

Comment: it gives me two errors
1. No such file or directory
2. syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ (4 - 1) ")

Comment: I only have this:
usage: split [-a sufflen] [-b byte_count] [-l line_count] [-p pattern]
             [file [prefix]]

Comment: @TheZoo: What's in `$inputDir`?

Comment: $inputDir
is the directory for the file I want to split (the directory includes the file itself)

Comment: @TheZoo: Full path? Relative path? Does the path contain some special characters (spaces, etc.)?

Comment: @TheZoo: Does the path contain some special characters (spaces, etc.)?

Comment: it actaully worked, as you missed a dollar sign for the chunk

Comment: @TheZoo: It shouldn't be needed.